# Lstm for continuos video

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, pytorch

Can we input a continuous video which contains sequences of both positive classes and negative classes to train LSTM, on several thousand of such videos?

> My overall objective is to mark videos realtime with particular
>   scenes(e.g. if I’ve 0-100 frames and frame number 30-60 contains some
>   yoga scenes, I need to mark them)

Right now the approach which I’m following is to split the video into two categories of positive sequences and negative sequences and train LSTM (on top of Mobnet CNN, FC replaced by LSTM layers).

> But somehow this does not give any improvement compared to Mobnet
>   alone when we run evaluation on non-split videos.

Both Mobnet and LSTM are trained separately. I save output of Mobnet(FC removed) in numpy arrays and then read these arrays for training LSTM.

Here is the sample of code used for this approach:

```
epochs = 250 
batch_size = 128 

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        in_size = 1024
        classes_no = 2
        hidden_size = 512 
        layer_no = 2 

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(in_size, hidden_size, layer_no, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, classes_no)

    def forward(self, input_seq):
        output_seq, _ = self.lstm(input_seq)
        last_output = output_seq[:,-1]
        class_predictions = self.linear(last_output)
        return class_predictions

def nploader(npfile):
    a = np.load(npfile)
    return a

def train():
    npdataloader = torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder('./featrs/',
            nploader, ['npy'], transform=None, target_transform=None)

    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(npdataloader,
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              shuffle=False,
                                              num_workers=1)

    model = Model().cuda()
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=100, gamma=0.8)
    model.train()

    for epoch in range(0, epochs):
        for input_seq, target in data_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(input_seq.cuda())
            err = loss(output.cuda(), target.cuda())
            err.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'lstm.ckpt')
```

Comment: If your question is if we _can_ then yes, you can train an LSTM on video. If your question is _why_ does it perform poorly, that's difficult to explain without rigorous research. As I understand, your `featrs` file contains the fully-connected activations, so you're using a pretrained and frozen Mobnet. I would guess that you may need to retrain the CNN and perhaps inject the LSTM data at an earlier layer than just the final classification.

Comment: @Jatentaki, can you share some reference code which has CNN+LSTM training together on videos(frame sequences of positive and negative cases together)

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot - my application was segmentation rather than classification plus the code is too large to release just like that. That being said, [here](https://gist.github.com/jatentaki/8037c1b8053566659000e2ca70f0788d) I posted an implemenetation of an LSTM unit with convolutional gates, so it can be embedded in CNNs.

Comment: @Jatentaki, i have some problem in preparing the dataloader for this new implementation. I have added a comment on top of your github link [here](https://gist.github.com/jatentaki/8037c1b8053566659000e2ca70f0788d). Can you help on that?